# FTP credentials for 'localhost'?

Tags: ftp, apache-http-server

How do you figure out your FTP credentials for your local computer?

I have apache set up on snow leopard and I am running a local install of Wordpress...I would just like to install plugins via the admin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be running an FTP server on your Mac, and then you use the credentials of any account on your Mac that has the permissions to write to the directories where WordPress installs its plugins.

I'm not a Mac guru, but I think you can enable the FTP server under `System Preferences | Sharing`.  You would then need to add the directory where your WordPress plugins get installed to the list of shared folders.

Comment: a) Is it hard to install an FTP Server and b) is it worth it just to install plugins in a folder?

Comment: I've admittedly not installed one on a Mac before, but I've done it on plenty of other platforms.  That said, I'm also a IT professional so my view of "hard" is a bit slanted.  Plugins can be installed manually, also.  That is an option if you are not comfortable with installing an FTP server.  Have a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you havnt got an FTP server installed, try looking up filezilla it's a free cross platform FTP server and client. You can setup users once installed, there are plenty of good tutorials on the net to help

On a side note with the right permissions wordpress can install themes etc using the filesystem without the need of an FTP server

Answer (score 0):

not to dredge up old posts, but OSX has an FTP server that's simply dormant. 
To load the FTP server, just run the Terminal app and run the command:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```