# WP Localhost Installation prompting for FTP access when deleting plugin etc

Tags: linux, ftp, localhost, wordpress

I know this question is asked quite some times already, but none of the suggested approaches works.

My problem: I have a wordpress installation on my localhost, but as soon as I try to delete plugins, install plugins, etc., it does not work. Either the interface prompts for FTP credentials, or simply fails.

What I've tried:

- 1 `sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist` according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/312110/ftp-credentials-for-localhost)
- 2 `sudo chown -R daemon /path/to/your/local/www/folder` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins)
- 3 `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins) and multiple other posts I found

Nothing works. 2 fails saying `Operation not permitted`.

I'm using XAMPP on a Mac, and the `htdocs` etc. folders only appear in the Finder when I click on "Mount" in the XAMPP interface, if that may help (is this actually normal?).

If it may also help: When installing WP on the localhost, wp was unable to generate the `wp-config.php` file due to "missing permissions". So I had to manually create the `wp-config.php` file and paste the accordingly provided contents into it. Hence it definitely seems to be a permission issue, but I can't get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found the solution. I've been struggling a whole day with this learning a little more about XAMPP etc., and I aim to prevent others form losing their time with this; hence I post the general procedure that worked below:

How to setup localhost wordpress environment:

1. Download & Install XAMPP
2. Start the XAMPP connection under the "General" Tab, the services under the "Services" tab, and the port forwarding 8080 -> 80 under the "Network" tab, to then access your application in your browser via http://localhost:8080. This should show you XAMPP's welcome page.
3. Go to localhost application's phpmyadmin (PhpMyAdmin Tab on the top right). This should redirect you to the DB server interface that comes with XAMPP.
4. Generate a new database within phpmyadmin, and remember the name.
5. Download WordPress ZIP
6. WP will prompt you for FTP accesses and / or fail to add / delete
   plugins, change admin languages, etc. etc., if you do not assure
   that the apache user running your localhost has read and write
   privileges on the files of your localhost application. These files
   are situated within the XAMPP's root directory (/opt/lampp), within
   the htdocs folder.

Note that XAMPP's /opt/lampp directory is not on your machine, but on XAMPP's VM(Would have probably taken me another day to find that out, without [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210703/xampp-vm-on-mac-cannot-found-the-opt-lampp-directory-after-mounted-this-in-st)). To thus change the access rights on it and prevent the above-mentioned problems, you have to act on that environment.

To do so, in the XAMPP window under the "General" Tab, click on "Open Terminal", which opens a terminal of the XAMPP VM. You can now simply do [this](https://dev.to/jovialcore/solvedunable-to-write-to-wp-configphp-file-on-linux-ubuntu-1noa):

`cd /opt/lampp`

`sudo chown -R username htdocs`

`chmod -R 777 htdocs`

Here, you have to assure that `username` is equal to the name of the user of your localhost application. You can get that one by creating a simple php file within your localhosts' root where you call (Thanks @Aboozar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins):

`echo(exec("whoami"));`

Using that username, this then changes the owner of the files contained within the htdocs folder, which is your entire set of your localhost applications, to the apache user launching the application, which is what you need to prevent wp from prompting you for FTP credentials when requesting to delete / install plugin files, etc.

7. When you go to "Volumes" in your XAMPP Panel and click on mount, this creates a linking instance of your localhost files (htdocs folder etc.) on your local machine. Click on "Explore" to go there. Now, you can create a folder within the htdocs folder of where you're at, e.g. my_new_site. And within that folder, you can unpack the contents of your downloaded WP ZIP file.
   You can also directly unpack the ZIP into the htdocs folder, but using subfolders allows to you to create (and easily access) multiple different testing applications on your localhost, separated by a simple folder structure.
8. Install your wp application on your localhost. For this, simply go to http://localhost:8080/my_new_site, or whatever directory name you specified in step 7). The WP Quick Installation should automatically start.
9. For this installation, just follow the instructions, while prompting the database name you specified in 4), "root" as the username, and an empty string as the db password (These are the values that are preset via your XAMPP installation).
10. After providing these things and clicking on "Submit", WP should automatically generate the `wp-config.php` file. If WP here tells you that there's a permission issue and that it cannot create the `wp-config.php` file on its own, this means that the apache user launching the WP application does not have the needed file permissions to modify the files of your localhost application (at least that was the case for me, and for the FTP prompt thing, the wp admin user selection, etc.). If you've carefully followed the steps under 6), this should not happen, so this is really important.
11. Et voila; now you should be able to use your localhost WP application as you're used to it on a usual server.
12. Finally, you can of course integrate the created localhost folder into your IDE, or for example configure your localhost instance as a testing deployment instance for your local wp testing projects (associate every subfolder of your `htdocs` folder to its respective project folder of your IDE, and associate the path to the localhost application folder as the local deployment instance; see for example [this for phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-local-server-configuration.html#example2).

Hope that helps!